# will I be able to find the size of file and save that file too

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

- if I use enctype="multipart/form-data" and paste the path of the file, will I be able to find the size of the file and save that file too.
- since I will be using the local path of the file, without using file attribute I should achieve.
- is that achievable
- or my approach is incorrect...
- providing my code in the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/9k1cs9ou/

```
<!-- language-all: lang-or-tag-here -->

url: $("#fname").val(),
      success: function () {
        alert("Size is " + request.getResponseHeader("Content-Length"));
        var resp = JSON.parse(response)
                alert(resp.status);
        // 10485760 -10MB
        if(request.getResponseHeader("Content-Length") <= 10485760/2){
          alert(request.getResponseHeader("Content-Length") <= 10485760/2);
          //$('.testingConfirmation').show();
        }
        else{
          alert(request.getResponseHeader("Content-Length") <= 10485760/2);
        }
      }
```

Comment: are you trying to use node.js for this task? or just front-end javascript code?

Comment: @turmuka thanks for your reply.. It's front-end javascript code

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have an input like this

```
  <input id="myFile" type="file" name="hola" value="">
```

Using jquery, whenever you upload something this will log the file size.

```
$('#myFile').bind('change', function() {
  alert(this.files[0].size); //file size
  console.log(this.files[0].size); //file size
});
```

Comment: but without the type="file" cant we achieve since I need to upload directly from the text box when I paste the local path of the file and hit save button

Comment: can I see your html input? also what you put inside the textbox? you can just get its length with javascript.

Comment: I will be giving input in the text box like this /Users/Raj/Desktop/sample.txt and I need to find the size of the file and upload it

Comment: Well sorry to say that, but I don't think you can upload files from your computer's drive by using plain javascript and without using `input file`. Why do you avoid using `input`? @veracity

Comment: if I use type=file I am seeing a upload button, I don't want to see that button. I just want to see a text box where can I copy the path and upload the file

Comment: cant we use this attribute enctype="multipart/form-data" and achieve it

Comment: in the form you can, if you use that, you are going to have to interact it with your back end programming language, since it encrypts the data as it sends it. do you use back end programming language at all?

Comment: I think what you can do is send an ajax request to the server, I am guessing you want to find sizes of the files that are in the host (*server*). Are you using Node.JS or php for you back end ? @veracity

Comment: also here is an example of what might help you @veracity `<button onclick="window.open('file:///C:/Windows/notepad.exe')">
    Launch notepad
</button>`   you just use window.open('file:///')

Comment: but how to open when I give as input in the textbox and after I save...it so confusing...can you update in my fiddle